# Vue-cli: Use template file other than index.html

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I am running a Vue 3 application using the vue-cli-service (webpack, no vite yet).

Because I want to re-use some of the code for a separate application, I need to create a separate HTML tempate file (e.g. `module.html`) to mount the application in.

However, it seems that the vue-cli and/or the webpack configuration do not let me specify a different html file to use as a template. The only filename that works is `index.html`.

How can I tell my application using the `vue.config.js` file or `vue-cli-service` command line to use a different html file as a template to inject the appliction in?

---

This is what I already tried:

**1) setting the `indexPath` property**

```
// in vue.config.js

defineConfig({
  indexpath: "module.html"
  //...
})
```

Result: No change, `index.html` is still being used to render the page.

**2) Using `historyApiFallback`**

```
// in vue.config.js

defineConfig({
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: "module.html",
    }
    // ...
  }
  // ...
})
```

Result: No change, `index.html` is still being used to render the page.

**3) using the `pages` property**

Using the `pages` property [should allow me](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages) to configure the `html-webpack-plugin` to use a different file.

```
// in vue.config.js

defineConfig({
  pages: {
    index: {
      entry: "src/module.js",
      template: "module.html",
    }
  }
  // ...
})
```

Result: This creates the following error in the console:

`Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename index.html`

Which makes me think, there must be a way outside of `pages` to set a different filename, which the application is trying to use. I don't see it however and have no idea where to look any more.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong. You are trying to create multiple layout for your Vue application right?

If that is the case, you should use [`vue-router`](https://router.vuejs.org/) nested routes to create an actual layout.

You can look at here for more detail https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-t1uatq

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I am trying to create another application that re-uses some of the code of the initial one. 

But it needs to be deployed and shipped separately

Comment: If that is the case, I recommend you trying to create a package or library instead. Then publish it to `npm`. When you want to re-use, you can install it back. Every adjustment you made to your package, they'll be apply to your applications. Creating 2 applications with just one Vue project doesn't sound like a good idea. Because for example, if your application A need some modification. You apply it to your re-used logic. Then, you'll have to apply it to your application B (which is deploying maybe). And if you decide to not apply it for B, so why do you think of this idea in the first place?

Comment: I agree in general. However that was not my question :-) 

I still think this should be possible. If I was creating the webpack config myself, I could probably figure it out. But I don't know how the vue-cli figures out the template path and what properties it uses under the hood. It works great usually, but it is not very transparent, I feel

Comment: OK, I understand. Since you said you know Webpack. I think you should take a look at [`configureWebpack`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration) option. This hook can help you mutate Webpack config. Finally, since you've said you just need to change `.html` template, I suggest you to build the app. After that, create your own `.html` and embed `div id="app"` and Vue script in just like the output `index.html`. Hope this idea can help you somehow XD

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to give absolute path to your html file here

1. setting the indexPath property

// in vue.config.js

```
defineConfig({
  indexpath: "module.html"
  //...
})
```

Comment: yes, I tried that.